# How to print diagrams (collection of DRepresentation) in my wordx using M2DOC

Tags: m2doc

Programmatically, I can get a collection of DPresentation diagrams.

But how I can print the representation of theses diagrams in my doc using M2DOC ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Sirius services](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_m2docsiriusservices.html), and more precisely to the [asImage()](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_m2docsiriusservices.html#orgeclipsesiriusviewpointdrepresentationasimage--orgobeonetworkm2docelementmimage) service. You can use it like that:

```
{m:myVar.anyServiceReturningADPresentation().asImage()}
```

optionally you can then apply an [image service](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_imageservices.html) like [fit()](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_imageservices.html#orgobeonetworkm2docelementmimagefitinteger-integer--orgobeonetworkm2docelementmimage).

Under Windows system you might also need to change the image size in the [Sirius settings](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/user/diagrams/Diagrams.html#Exportingimages).